# How to use multiple google accounts, but allow only one to locate my phone in device manager

Tags: google-account, privacy, android-device-manager, accounts

I am using multiple google accounts, both private and company accounts.

I want to see all calendars in my Calendar app. Events in all calendars. Same with Gmail. I want to be logged in and be able to switch between all gmail accounts.

But I don't want my company account (To which I am not the only person to have access I think) to be able to store and backup my contacts, my chrome settings, and privately visited websites, and all private activity.

Right now logging to any of those accounts and going to android device manager, I can locate or wipe my phone. I want to allow it only on my main account.

How can I control that?

Android 5.0.2 MIUI 7.0

Answer (score 1):

By going to the sync settings for each account (as shown in the image below), you can control what each account 'sees'. For the 'public' account, turn off all syncing besides Gmail and Calendar.

Unfortunately, this will not address Android Device Manager access. To do this, you must open the Google Settings app and navigate to Google > Security. Below Android Device Manager heading, you will be able to turn off it's features.
Source: [Set up Android Device Manager](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3265955?hl=en)

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: Account Sync Settings Page]

Comment: I'm using Android 5.0.2 and MIUI 7.0. I have trouble locating Google Settings. Can't See Android Device Manager Section

Comment: Google Settings should be an app in the app drawer. If it is not there you might have to Reset the App Data for Play Store as mentioned here: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/255881-google-settings-app.html#post2611390

Comment: Ok, I got it. But the problem remains. I am only able to entirely switch on or off the android device manager access. For all connected accounts at once. Cannot choose just one. Logging on my work email I can wipe my private phone.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is currently the only way to do this.