# Use multiple Google accounts, but allow only one to locate my phone in device manager

Tags: google-account, privacy, android-device-manager

My question is basically identical to this question from 2016 (I would have commented on it but I don't have sufficient reputation):

[How to use multiple google accounts, but allow only one to locate my phone in device manager](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139793/how-to-use-multiple-google-accounts-but-allow-only-one-to-locate-my-phone-in-de)

I would like to know if there is a way to have two Google accounts added to my phone (one personal and one work account), while only allowing one account the ability to Find My Device and perform a remote wipe.
Has anything regarding this changed since 2016?

Comment: Are you aware of [Android Enterprise Mobile Management](https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview)? You might want to [edit](https://android.stackexchange.com/posts/206248/edit) your question to provide more context.

Comment: I am aware, but I do not want to use EMM, nor should the assumption be that an additional account necessarily means a managed enterprise account. I simply want to be able to use Google account A as my primary account with all the bells and whistles, and also use Google account B for Gmail and Calendar and Drive *only* - i.e. account B should not be linked to any other account "features", such as Find My Device, Remote Wipe, etc.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Please read [How to Ask](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Unless the author of a post writes it down, no one knows what the author has looked at or tried. For example have you looked at adding Google account B as a secondary user which won't have access to Find My Device, at the cost of having to switch users which may be unacceptable. Also you haven't stated any limitations on device (manufacturer, OS version etc.).

Comment: I have been wanting something like this for a while, not being able to add the secondary account because of this is a real pain.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this in the meantime by chance?

Comment: Wow, can't believe it's been 5 years. Unfortunately, I have not. It's not as comfortable as actually adding an account on Android, and definitely not what I originally asked about, but I have found workarounds for Gmail and Calendar. For Gmail, add the secondary account as an IMAP email account. If you're somehow limited by SSO/OTP, look into Google "app passwords" for basic user:pass auth. For Calendar, the DAVx5 app can operate as a middleman for syncing calendars (caldav) and possibly contacts from Google (cloud) to Android.